# mysql and php suddenly case-sensitive?

Tags: php, mysql, case-insensitive

Basically, I've changed something in my php login code and now when I log in, the MySQL requires that the case matches?!

```
    $match = "select * from users where username = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."';";

    echo $match;
```

If my username's CaSe doesn't match the database then it doesn't return any rows.

If a user registers as ADMIN then I want them to be able to log in as "admin" or "AdMiN" etc. any ideas?

Many thanks :)

Comment: What's the collation of `username`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The collation for that column has changed, I guess. See [this MySQL page about case sensitivity in string comparison](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html) to learn more. To insulate yourself from problems like that, something like:

```
$match = "select * from users where UPPER(username) = '".strtoupper($username)."' and password = '".$password."';";
```

is the usual trick. As others have observed, though, understanding how collation works in the database and using it appropriately is the best solution. Getting the database collation right and relying on it should allow the database to use any index on the username column, rather than scanning the table.

And also make sure that you're avoiding [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks -- what happens in your current code if a user enters a username containing a single quote?

You may also want to consider what characters you'll allow as usernames, and what character set you're using -- is "René" a valid username? Will it successfully pass from your front-end, through the database and back out unmolested by character set problems? Joel Spolsky's [excellent article on Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) is probably worth a read at some point.

Comment: For performance reasons it's better to make sure the collation is right but your solution is a good way to repair a bad design if you cannot change the tables ;)

Comment: @David Yes, absolutely. And congratulations on having a username that illustrates my point about unicode characters :D

Comment: `...WHERE username = '"$username"' COLLATE utf8_general_ci` is on the other hand a bit more elegant and allows the query to use indexes. (of course use the collation you need)

Comment: @Mchl @David I've updated with information on performance implications. @Mchl -- are you sure that will allow the use of indexes? I'd have thought that if you change the column collation on the fly in the query, it'd have problems using an existing, non-CI index?

Comment: Hmm... actually the only way to be sure is to EXPLAIN the query and see

Comment: Ok, tested it. The index will not be used. Shame I can't edit the comment anymore.

Comment: @Mchl Thanks for checking! I thought that might be the case. It's definitely still worth mentioning on-the-fly collation manipulation, though, as it can definitely be more elegant, and could still outperform a force-to-uppercase...

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer Matt :)